# Change every n-th element of a row in a 2d numpy array depending on the row number

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have a 2d array:

```
H = 12
a = np.ones([H, H])
print(a.astype(int))

[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

The goal is, for every row `r` to substitute every `r+1`-th (starting with 0th) element of that row with 0.
Namely, for the 0th row substitute every 'first' (i.e. all of them) element with 0. For the 1st row substitute every 2nd element with 0. And so on.

It can trivially be done in a loop (the printed array is the *desired* output):

```
for i in np.arange(H):
    a[i, ::i+1] = 0

print(a.astype(int))

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Can I make use the vectorisation power of numpy here and avoid looping? Or it is not possible?

Comment: `a = np.arange(H); ((a % (a+1)[:, None]) != 0).astype('int')`, I doubt this is much faster or easier to understand

Comment: This is perfect. Can you make it an answer so I could mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `np.arange` and broadcast `modulo` over itself

```
import numpy as np

H = 12

a = np.arange(H)
((a % (a+1)[:, None]) != 0).astype('int')
```

Output

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: great answer! Out of curiosity why do you answer your questions as wiki?

Comment: That's probably wise ;) It just makes it not always clear who answered, but that's minor